# Oracle compile view sql

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-construction, ant

As part of our ANT based deploys we run some sql against an Oracle database.

The deploys are set to fail if any `sql` errors occur.  (We do this using `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK` in our SQL files and using the ant `exec` command with `failonerror=true` to run the sql).

We would like to add to our deploy sql files some sql that will compile (or re-compile) certain views and have the deploy fail if the compile fails.  Anyone know the sql (or whatever) that will allow us to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to do more than "ALTER VIEW xxx COMPILE"?